# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '...' imported by the module '...'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I'm trying to import my own custom module into the app module and I keep getting this error.

```
"Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'ActionsService' imported by the module 'ReduxStoreModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation."
```

It wants me to add a @NgModule annotation, but I have @NgModule in both of my Modules. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

---

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { ReduxStoreModule } from './Redux-Store/redux-store.module'

@NgModule( {
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
        ,ReduxStoreModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
} )
export class AppModule { }
```

---

**redux-store.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { NgReduxModule } from '@angular-redux/store'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { ActionsService } from './actions'

const ImportsExports = [
    ActionsService
    ,NgReduxModule
]

@NgModule( {
    imports: ImportsExports
    ,exports: ImportsExports
} )
export class ReduxStoreModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

services should be under providers not under modules, remove **`ActionsService`** from module and add it under provider,

```
const ImportsExports = [
  NgReduxModule
]
```